# Выделение памяти под элементы структуры

Tags: c

Есть структура, которая должна быть считана с файла:

```
typedef struct config
{
    char* delete_first;
    char* delete_first_ten;
    char* delete_last;
    char* delete_last_ten;
    char* delete_all;
} cnfg;
```

Я узнаю необходимый размер для нее и выделяю память под нее :

```
    cnfg* var;
    if ((var = (cnfg*)malloc(size)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Allocate error.");
        return  EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

Далее пытаюсь считать строку из файла в первый элемент, но получаю ошибку, делаю вот так:

```
fgets(var->delete_first, size, file);
```

Функция, которая вычисляет размер, необходимый для структуры:

```
int file_size(FILE* file)
{
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); // Установка указателя на конец файла (0 смещение относительно SEEK_END).
    int size = ftell(file); // Количество байт, на которое смещен указатель.
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); // Возврат указателя на начало файла.
    return size; 
}
```

При компиляции вылезает исключение. В чем я не прав? Спасибо!

Comment: @andreymal, да, сейчас отредактирую, спасибо!

Comment: А вообще вы выделили память под пять указателей `char*`, но не поместили в них никакие действительные адреса, а значит `var->delete_first` и остальные четыре указателя указывают в никуда

Comment: @andreymal, получается мне нужно выделять память под каждый элемент структуры отдельно?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, вы и записывали точно так же, так что в вашем файле просто содержатся значения каких-то указателей от предыдущего запуска.

Проще всего было бы использовать структуру с уже выделенной памятью - типа

```
typedef struct config
{
    char delete_first[100];
    char delete_first_ten[100];
    char delete_last[100];
    char delete_last_ten[100];
    char delete_all[100];
} cnfg;
```

Ну, или не 100, а какие-то иные размеры... Если, конечно, речь идет о строках. Тогда такую структуру можно писать и читать с помощью `fwrite`/`fread`. Но если нет - то надо возиться с каждой строкой отдельно, выясняя ее размер, выделяя соответствующую память etc etc.